# Is there any way to find out where iOS app is downloaded, however never launched?

Tags: ios, nsnotification

Is there any way to find out where iOS app is downloaded, however never launched?

I am trying following things for that - 
1. Send a notification, and on Didreceivenotification handler try to figure out how many didnt click on the notification / iOS App?
How can we send data to the back end when app is just in downloaded state and not even lunched even once. What is the stage of the app when its just downloaded (Inactive  / suspended?)

Currently, I am using NSURLConnection to send data to back end in the Didreceivenotification, however NSURLConnection request gets lost.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO.

Your app cannot receive notifications,

Until you have:
launched app
registered for notifications
and succeeded in registering for notifications.

On a successful registration, you'll send your device token to the third party push notification service (or in house if you are using that).

Once that is done, if you send a push notification, didReceiveNotification is called

Comment: I see. I have a follow up question? Is there any way to find out after you send notification, how many users clicked on the notification and how many people didnt click on the noficiation event (badge)?

Comment: if you are trying to know how many people tapped on the notification, when your app was not in the foreground, (either by tapping the banner on top, or by swiping left to right on the notification center), then yes, there is a way to do it. There's no simple iOS api that lets you do this though

Comment: you'll have to ask a separate question for that, so that its easier to post an answer and is better to keep these questions/answers on separate thread

Comment: Kool. Let me do that. Thanks Nitin for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are distributing an enterprise app, you could set it up on some server that counts the number of downloads.

If your app is in the App Store, iTunes Connect will tell you how many times it has been *purchased*. This can be helpful for giving you an idea for how many times it was downloaded, but it doesn't take into account how many times the same user actually downloaded an app - they only purchase it once, but may install it on multiple devices or even on the same device multiple times (deleting, reinstalling, etc.).

There is hope that Apple will add more analytics data to iTunesConnect. You could file a radar with Apple to let them know about your need.

As for how many times your app is launched, you could handle that with any number of analytics solutions, or even a custom solution. Keep in mind though, a user may never open your app with a network connection which could also throw off your analytics numbers.